# Is it possible to run only specific tests on Cypress through support/index.js?

Tags: javascript, npm, cypress, config, test-runner

I am trying to run only specific test. Say I have 50 test files inside integration folder and want only 10 of them to run. I am trying to configure this from support/index.js file like:

`import './commands'`
`import '../integration/login.spec.js'`
`import '../integration/admin.spec.js'`
`import '../integration/customer.spec.js'`

I want to only display the selected files (login.spec.js, admin.spec.js and customer.spec.js) on the test runner of Cypress. I don't want other test files to display. But the above code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Fody mentioned in the another answer, adding another dummy spec file approach does work.

Hence adding a detailed explanation on that approach in cypress 10.0.3, Windows OS

Lets's say below is your script folder structure

```
cypress
  e2e
    small-Run
      theDummytest.cy.js
    Module-A
      test-Module-A.cy.js
    Module-B
      SubModule-BB
        test-SubModule-BB.cy.js
```

And this is how, you implement the dummy test file approach

```
import '../Module-A/test-Module-A.cy.js'
import '../Module-B/SubModule-BB/test-SubModule-BB.cy.js'
```

And in you CLI/CI?CMD run, you would be using the below line to invoke that selective script tests

```
npx cypress run --spec cypress\e2e\small-Run\*.cy.js
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not bother using the `support/index.js`, just make a dummy spec and run that

```js
// my-top-10-tests.spec.js

import './login.spec.js' 
import './admin.spec.js' 
import './customer.spec.js'
// and so on
```

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: It's pretty simple and straightforward, not much to get wrong.

Comment: Actually my question was whether is it possible to display only the specs you want to run on the test runner window. Actually the method that you have mentioned in the answer will work by using a command. But I only want to display (login.spec.js, admin.spec.js and customer.spec.js) files on the test runner window.